# How can I locate a file to edit it in the file manager of my hosting?

Tags: web, frontend, edit, file-manager

I need to edit the home of a website, but I cannot locate the file that contains the home in the hosting file manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggz33.png)

I have checked folder by folder in the website's file manager, but I can't locate the home to edit it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTOpq.png)

Comment: It looks like you have a content management system (CMS) installed.  It likely uses a front controller defined in .htaccess.   What are the rules from there?